# JSX text in paragraph loads after few second

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome, jsx

i have my portfolio project in react

but on page first load text appears after few seconds. but when it is loaded and you refresh page, there is no problem, paragraph appears Immediatly. but if you open new tab or incognito tab and enter on page, paragraph appears after few seconds. but if you click anywhere text appears.[here is a video](https://youtu.be/k85U6V6Cjxw). this happens only in chrome. i dont have any timers in code

you can check it [www.devweb.cc](http://www.devweb.cc)

any help plz

```
<p ref={aboutMeParag}> 
'Im a Frontend Web Developer building the Front-End of Websites and Web Applications that leads to the success of the overall product. Check out some of my work in the Projects section.<br/><br/> Im open to Job opportunities where I can contribute, learn and grow. If you have a good opportunity that matches my skills and experience then dont hesitate to contact me.'
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The font that you are using `FiraGO` takes approx 1 sec to load, see your network tab.
That could be the issue on the first time as it takes approx 1 s to show your text and during subsequent renders,its memory cached. Can you check?

Comment: i removed font from whole code but still same.